# How do I output bucketed parquet files in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

**Background**

I have 8k parquet files representing a table that I want to bucket by a particular column, creating a new set of 8k parquet files.  I want to do this so that joins from other data sets on the bucketed column won't require re-shuffling.  The documentation I'm working off of is here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning

**Question**

What's the easiest way to output parquet files that are bucketed?  I want to do something like this:

```
df.write()
    .bucketBy(8000, "myBucketCol")
    .sortBy("myBucketCol")
    .format("parquet")
    .save("path/to/outputDir");
```

But according to the documentation linked above:

> Bucketing and sorting are applicable only to persistent tables

I'm guessing I need to use `saveAsTable` as opposed to `save`.  However `saveAsTable` doesn't take a path.  Do I need to create a table prior to calling `saveAsTable`.  Is it in that table creation statement that I declare where the parquet files should be written?  If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sql("drop table if exists myTable");
spark.sql("create table myTable ("
    + "myBucketCol string, otherCol string ) "
    + "using parquet location '" + outputPath + "' "
    + "clustered by (myBucketCol) sorted by (myBucketCol) into 8000 buckets"
);
enlDf.write()
    .bucketBy(8000, "myBucketCol")
    .sortBy("myBucketCol")
    .format("parquet")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable("myTable");
```

Comment: That looks bizarre.  You have to use sql strings to do bucketing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `path` option:

```
df.write()
    .bucketBy(8000, "myBucketCol")
    .sortBy("myBucketCol")
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", "path/to/outputDir")
    .saveAsTable("whatever")
```